# How to display the most duplicated data from txt file into MsgBox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck! i'm trying to read a txt file with the data as below:

LEE
JOSH
JOSH
ANDY
MANDY
LINDA 
LEE
JOSH
AMANDA

the txt file is updating all the time. So, i like to read this file and then display in msgbox the name that is most duplicated. In this case the MsgBox will show JOSH.

Can anyone help me please?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
Dim result = File _
    .ReadAllLines("test.txt") _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x) _
    .Select(Function(x) New With { _
        Key .Word = x.Key, _
        Key .Count = x.Count() _
    }) _
    .OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Count) _
    .First()
Console.WriteLine("Word: {0}, Occurrences: {1}", result.Word, result.Count)
```

Comment: hi there thank you. why the result displaying in msgbox doesn't work? It says that {"Conversion from string "AIMIE" to type 'Integer' is not valid."} Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: @strugger, try calling `.ToString()`. Also please show your code. How do you expect someone be able to help you without showing what have you tried?